# Delete default user property - SPS-SipAddress

Tags: sharepoint-server, user-profile-property

is it Ok to delete the "SPS-SipAddress" from the User-Properties?
I have a problem with the AD-Sync and want to "recreate" it.

But i dont know if there are any refferences on the default property or if i get any problems when i delete it.
Thanks!

Comment: Did you already try to clear the SPS-SipAddress field for all users instead of entirely removing the property? I could provide you a small PowerShell for that task.

Comment: Hi Mheld, i dont understand how this should help. When i clear the field for all users i still have the problem that my sync is not working well.

Comment: Why do you think deleting the property will solve your problem?

Comment: I will not solve my problem.. but no matter if I delete it or hide it, if there is a dependency I will not get it linked in the new object. So if I could delete it, I would know that there is no dependency and I could create a custom attribute without problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the article below on how delete default user property.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/add-edit-or-delete-custom-properties-for-a-user-profile

As far as I know, delete default user property doesn't cause any problems.

Comment: Thanks! But this article is for "custom"-Properties.. not for "default"-Properties. I know there are some properties which are mapped to the mysites. If you delete them, you cant open mysites anymore. Thats why i am afraid to do this change...

Comment: Since you're worried that deleting default user properties might have some bad effects, I recommend that you try to hide them instead of deleting them.
In the User Profile Service Application > Manage user properties, the properties can be hidden from users my site by unchecking the check boxes under "display settings" of the user property.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting a default property seems to be impossible. I tried on several farms and wasn't able either via GUI (delete button has no effect) nor via PowerShell:
[image: Deleting not possible]

You mentioned dependencies in your comment. Can you more details about that error? Maybe we can help you with the root-cause of your problem.